# Warning: comparison of constant ‘0’ with boolean expression is always false

Tags: c++, boolean

I'm compiling with Boost 0.17.4 on Ubuntu 18. Can someone please give me the correct expression here to avoid the warning on build.

```
init.cpp:1059:72: warning: comparison of constant ‘0’ with boolean expression is always false [-Wbool-compare]
     if (GetBoolArg("-rpcserialversion", DEFAULT_RPC_SERIALIZE_VERSION) < 0)
```

In this case, we are trying to make sure DEFAULT_RPC_SERIALIZE_VERSION is a negative number.

I've tried looking at other repos upstream, but apparently lots of devs are happy to live with this warning. And my C++ is 'Hello World' level.

Comment: What is `GetBoolArg`?

Comment: `if (true < 0)` isn't exactly sensible code. No boolean value is `< 0` when interpreted as an `int`.

Comment: This is the file: https://github.com/goldcoin/goldcoin/blob/goldcoin-master/src/init.cpp I think not equal to '0' could also be positive.

Comment: I can only guess that they meant `GetArg` instead of `GetBoolArg`, but that is one huge mess of a code. The best course of action would be reporting the issue to the mainteners and waiting for them to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The function `GetBoolArg()` is defined in [util.h](https://github.com/goldcoin/goldcoin/blob/goldcoin-master/src/util.h) as:

```
/*
 * Return boolean argument or default value
 *
 * @param strArg Argument to get (e.g. "-foo")
 * @param default (true or false)
 * @return command-line argument or default value
 */
bool GetBoolArg(const std::string& strArg, bool fDefault);
```

This functions returns a `bool` type.
0 casted to `bool` is `false` but the comparison of a `bool` < `false` can never be true because `bool` can never be **less** than `false`.

Also, the second argument to `GetBoolArg()` is `bool fDefault` however the constant passed to it, the `DEFAULT_RPC_SERIALIZE_VERSION` is defined as `static const unsigned int` in [server.h](https://github.com/goldcoin/goldcoin/blob/goldcoin-master/src/rpc/server.h) not as a `bool` type that the `GetBoolArg()` expects.

Also, the first argument `"-rpcserialversion"` suggest that the argument to be retrieved is not a true/false (boolean) value.

All of this suggests that this is a bug and a function `Getarg` should be used instead of `GetBoolArg` in this place of the code.